# How to print the value of a tkinter Scale widget?

Tags: python, tkinter, printing, tkinter-scale

Can somebody tell me why this will not print the value? I want to print the output of the `Scale` widget every time it changes.

```
from tkinter import *

master= Tk()
master.geometry('500x500+0+0')

def print_value(val):
    print val

c1 = Scale(master, from_=255, to=0, length =400,width =100, troughcolor = 'blue',command=print_value)
c1.grid(row=1,column=2)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What version are you using? `tkinter` isn't a valid module name in 2.7, and `print val` isn't valid syntax in 3.X. Also, where is `root` defined? Please provide runnable code that exhibits your problem.

Comment: In future, please provide all pertinent information, including the precise error message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using `Python 3` then you should change `print val` to `print(val)` as in Python3 `print` is a function, not an operator.

Also you should probably replace `root` with `master` on the last line as there is no `root` variable in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Using Python 2.7 with this code works perfect:

```
import Tkinter

master= Tkinter.Tk()
master.geometry('500x500+0+0')

def print_value(val):
    print val

c1 = Tkinter.Scale(master, from_=255, to=0, length =400,width =100, troughcolor = 'blue',command=print_value)
c1.grid(row=1,column=2)

master.mainloop()
```

I don't have Python 3 here but it should work like this:

```
from tkinter import *

master= Tk()
master.geometry('500x500+0+0')

def print_value(val):
    print (val)

c1 = Scale(master, from_=255, to=0, length =400,width =100, troughcolor = 'blue',command=print_value)
c1.grid(row=1,column=2)

main.mainloop()
```

Comment: im using python 3, and it says 'invalid syntax' and refers to the var after print.

Comment: In python 3 print is a function, so it has to be print(val)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change you last line:

```
root.mainloop()
```

by

```
master.mainloop()
```